# Overriding default Java AES round key method

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm reverse engineering an interesting piece of javascript malware that uses AES 256 to encrypt/decrypt however it uses a custom implementation of aesjs that has no direct key input. Instead the key has already been expanded and the round keys have been hardcoded, how is this something I could replicate in java? I've looked into overwriting the aes encryption class but am struggling to find the relevant method.

Comment: You could always try to find (or write!) a pure Java implementation of AES. Or, assuming that the round keys are indeed the result of normal AES key expansion, [just reconstruct the original key from them](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15200/how-secure-is-the-aes-master-key-if-round-keys-are-found).